# Programmatically adding a style causes exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

Hiy

I am working on a project in silverlight and stumbled accross an issue I can't seem to solve.

I have a class where I build a canvas programmatically (for printing). This contains a barcode, for which I use the Telerik Barcode element. By default it shows the value in your barcode underneath the bar, but I wanted to remove this and found that I could that by doing:

```
<telerik:RadBarcodeEAN13 Height="120" Width="425" Text="123456789012">
<telerik:RadBarcodeEAN13.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Viewbox"> 
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>
</telerik:RadBarcodeEAN13.Resources>
</telerik:RadBarcodeEAN13>
```

I tried translating this to code, to do it programmatically:

```
RadBarcodeCodebar bar = new RadBarcodeCodebar();
bar.Text = number;

System.Windows.Style style = new Style(typeof(Viewbox));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Viewbox.VisibilityProperty, "Collapsed"));

bar.Style = style;
```

Unfortunately this last line throws:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
Message= [Line: 0 Position: 0]
LineNumber=0
LinePosition=0
StackTrace:
   bij MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   bij MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_Style(Style value)
   bij SilverlightTestApplication.CardPrinter.SendStaffCardToPrinter(CardInfo card)
InnerException:
```

If I remove the style assignment, it works as it should.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points you need to fix.

**First**, value of `VisibilityProperty` should be `Visibility` enumeration instead of string :

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Viewbox.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));
```

**Second**, looking at the XAML, style is declared within resources element instead of style element. So corresponding C# code for that part of XAML is as follow :

```
bar.Resources.Add(typeof(Viewbox), style);
```

the first argument of `.Add()` method is resource key. And in case of style without key, it should be filled with type of target element of the style.

Your code should work fine after those fixes.